# Moving axes labels in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How can one have an axes labels (`x` and `z` near the axis) like this:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can place the axis labels at the tip of the axis lines by setting

```
axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$, ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty
]
\addplot [very thick, domain=0:10] {x+rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to align the labels next to the arrow tips if `axis y line=left,` and `axis x line=bottom,` is chosen instead of `axis lines=middle,` and the y-domain becomes negative, e.g. with `\addplot [very thick, domain=-4:8] {x+rnd-3};`?

Comment: @kromuchi: Sure! Set `every axis x label/.style={at={(rel axis cs:1,0)}, anchor=west}, every axis y label/.style={at={(rel axis cs:0,1)}, anchor=south}`.

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I also figured out that `every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.south east)}, anchor=north},` (or with `anchor=west` depending what you want) would do the same.