# How to draw a normal curve using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I only create this:

[image]

With this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin = 0, axis x line = bottom, axis y line=middle, 
         legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [name path=A, domain=0:6,cyan, thick]{x};

%\legend{$f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)$}

%\path [name path=yaxis] (0,0)--(0,1000);  %<---- third path

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want this image (I don't care f(x), I only care the form) :
[image]

Any ideas
Many thanks

Comment: Have a look for pgfplots normal curve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample of code based on your own one that may do what you are expecting :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normalcurve}{0}{\pgfmathparse{1.5*1/exp(((x-3)^2)/2)}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$V$, ylabel=$P$,
        xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
        ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=south},
        ticks=none, ymin = 0, ymax=1.6, axis x line = bottom, axis y line=middle,
         legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [name path=A, domain=0:6,cyan, thick, samples=150] {normalcurve};
\draw[dashed] (3,1.5) -- (3,0);
\node at (3,1.5) {\textbullet};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result :

[image: ![enter image description here]

This code may be improve, I hope it may be useful.

Comment: Its perfect. But only 2 things for finally: 1. Do you know to put xlabel={$V$},  ylabel={$P$}, like my image? 2. Do you know to remove the numers in the axes? Thanks

Comment: I edit my answer. Concerning labels, this subject may prove useful : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97019/moving-axes-labels-in-pgfplots